# Cloud composer issue with datasets in Australia region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I was trying to use cloud composer to schedule and orchestrate Bigquery jobs. Bigquery tables are in australia-southeast1 region.The cloud composer environment was created in us-central1 region(As composer is not available in Australia region). When I try below command , it throws a vague error. The same setup worked fine when I tried with datasets residing in EU and US.

```
Command:
gcloud beta composer environments run bq-schedule --location us-central1 test -- my_bigquery_dag input_gl 8-02-2018

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 7, in <module>
    exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 528, in test
    ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1583, in run
    session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1492, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py", line 98, in execute
    self.create_disposition, self.query_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 499, in run_query
    return self.run_with_configuration(configuration)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 868, in run_with_configuration
    err.resp.status)
Exception: ('BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s', 404)

Is there any workaround to resolve this issue?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your dataset resides in `australia-southeast1`, BigQuery created a job in the same location by default, which is `australia-southeast1`. However, the Airflow in your Composer environment was trying to get the job's status without specifying location field.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get

This has been fixed by my [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/4695) and it has been merged to master.

To work around this, you can extend the BigQueryCursor and override the run_with_configuration() function with location support.

Comment: Thanks Ryan . Would you mind sharing a code sample for the same?